# How to get parts of speech information in ruta from German novel uima ruta example?

Tags: uima, ruta, dkpro-core

I created and executed the German Novel example project from scratch. The output contains tags like Lemma & Token, but can't find any features giving the token's parts of speech information. How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

The part of speech information should be stored in the `pos` feature of the token. These annotations are also in the index of the CAS, e.g., there should be annotations of the type `de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos.POS` like `de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos.N`. If this information is missing, then there is a problem with the POS Tagger.

Comment: Does it mean that there could be some issue with the TreeTagger installation ? How to resolve it ?

Comment: It's described in the German tutorial, and there is a [screencast on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUgVncR5vwg). I haven't done it for some time as DKPro now provides easier options to install/run the tagger. Maybe it is easier to replace the TreeTagger with the OpenNLP one.